# Запуск bash скрипта от имени другого пользователя

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Имеется следующая ситуация. Есть пользователь user, у которого нет прав суперпользователя. Есть апач, который является классическим www-data. Конечно есть root-суперпользователь. 
Задача: www-data должен иметь право запускать скрипт /var/www/example/script3.sh (user:user, 700) без пароля.
После некоторых поисков вышел на решение с использованием sudoers, которое отлично сработало на 2 других скриптах, которые апач запускает как root. Но это решение не работает в случае с обычным пользователем.
Содержание sudoers:

```
# Работает отлично:
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/var/www/example/script1.sh
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/var/www/example/script2.sh
# Не работает
www-data ALL=(user) NOPASSWD:/var/www/example/script3.sh
```

В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: как именно пытаешься запустить от пользователя `script3.sh`?

Comment: Обычный http запрос, срабатывает php функция exec();

Comment: что именно в `exec()` написано?

Comment: exec('/var/www/example/script3.sh');

Comment: что-то мне не вирится, что в таком варианте первые 2 «работают» от имени root'а.

Comment: Там sudo есть, но без параметров. Поэтому и работает. Сказывается незнание линукс, спасибо, решение подошло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> exec('/var/www/example/script3.sh');
> ```

sudo — не автомагический системный демон, который запускает произвольный скрипт, прописанный в `/etc/sudoers` от имени указанного пользователя, а простая утилита. Таким образом, необходимо явно указывать, что необходимо выполнять через sudo и от имени какого пользователя это делать:

```
exec('sudo -u user /var/www/example/script3.sh');
```

Как вариант, по необходимости можно также сделать отдельный proxy-скрипт,
**/var/www/example/scrip3-proxy.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u user /var/www/example/script3.sh
```

**my.php**:

```
exec('/var/www/example/script3-proxy.sh');
```